# Why is Wolfram Alpha wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

I calculated $$\tan 75^o - [\cot 13^o\cdot \cot 23^o \cdot \tan 31^o \cdot \tan 35^o\cdot \tan41^o]$$ and I got a nonzero answer: 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%2875%29-[cot%2813%29*cot%2823%29*tan%2831%29*tan%2835%29*tan%2841%29]

But someone posted this problem in a forum as an identity, i.e. $$\tan 75^o = \cot 13^o\cdot \cot 23^o \cdot \tan 31^o \cdot \tan 35^o\cdot \tan 41^o$$

So my question is: Should the answer be $0$? And if so, why is Wolfram Alpha giving a nonzero answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe WolframAlpha interprets the inputs as radians, not degrees. Verify that...

Comment: look at the numberline

Comment: Besides the above explanations, WA is, astonishing (?) enough, **not** infallible: it makes mistakes, and quite a few, when trying to do some stuff. Be careful with that.

Comment: Yes, it does. What you see is a rounding error - or maybe the identity isn't actually one.

Comment: Is the "identity" using $\cot(13°)$ or is that a typo?

Comment: Suggest you have an ordinary  calculator available to do stuff with numbers and just evaluating elementary functions. For one thing, you could get a numerical approximation for your difference.

Comment: @AnalysisIncarnate If Mathematica gives you $0$, then it's (almost certainly) a rounding error, since WA doesn't use the full power of symbolic manipulation and therefore computes the product as a floating point value.

Comment: If there's a proof where the identity was posted, and Mathematica says it's $0$ exactly, then that's a strong indication that the proof is correct. If there's no proof given, then Mathematica saying it's exactly $0$ it's still a strongish indication that it's an identity.

Comment: Okay. I'd still put stronger faith in Mathematica than in WA, for the one, you need to pay a lot of money, the other is free. I think there's a business reason to make the expensive bit better/more sophisticated.

Comment: Probably not a coincidence. Playing around with the addition theorems may lead to the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Try [asking it to do it numerically more explicitly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%2875%29-%5Bcot%2813%29*cot%2823%29*tan%2831%29*tan%2835%29*tan%2841.%29%5D) (putting in a decimal point makes even mathematica assume you're using approximate numeric values, and so it will use approximate numerical methods) and you'll see that the value you get is well within the default tolerance value of the WA engine.  Curiously, you'll note the output it gives for "Result" and "Number line" don't really agree.  The result value is of substantially higher precision, and substantially closer to zero in terms of how negative the exponent is (and if you ask it for more digits, you'll get even closer to zero).  Presumably it is using different methods for each--lower precision ones for the number line, namely--, but we'd need to know more about the precise workings of these features to know for sure.